# Access STATIC_URL from within a custom inclusion template tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I have created a custom [inclusion template tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) that accepts a single `Update` model object.

**Template tag:**

```
@register.inclusion_tag('update_line.html')
def update_line(update):
    return {'update': update}
```

**update_line.html**:

```
<tr><td class="update">{{ update }}</td><td class="ack">
<img id="update-{{ update.pk }}" class="ack-img" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/acknowledge.png" alt="Acknowledge" /></td></tr>
```

The problem is that `{{ STATIC_URL }}` is not available in my inclusion template tag template, even though I am using the `django.core.context_processors.static` context processor so `{{ STATIC_URL }}` is available to all of my 'normal' templates that aren't being processed through an inclusion template tag.

Is there a way I can get the `STATIC_URL` from within my inclusion template tag template without doing something nasty like manually getting it from settings and explicitly passing it as a context variable?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay. Just figured this out after posting the question:

Instead of using `{{ STATIC_URL }}` in my inclusion template, I use the `get_static_prefix` tag from the `static` template tags:

**update_line.html**:

```
{% load static %}

<tr><td class="update">{{ update }}</td><td class="ack">
<img id="update-{{ update.pk }}" class="ack-img" src="{% get_static_prefix %}img/acknowledge.png" alt="Acknowledge" /></td></tr>
```

---

## **Update**

I believe the correct way to do this now (django 1.5+) is:

**update_line.html**:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<tr><td class="update">{{ update }}</td><td class="ack">
<img id="update-{{ update.pk }}" class="ack-img" src="{% static 'my_app/img/acknowledge.png' %}" alt="Acknowledge" /></td></tr>
```

Comment: I guess this is because context processors aren't applied to templates rendered manually (or rendered using inclusion template tags). Today I learned.

Comment: With Django 1.7, it also works using `{% load static %}`

Answer (score 2):

Inside your template tag code, you can do what you like: so you can easily import `STATIC_URL` from `settings` yourself.

Comment: Yea, I knew that was an option but I was wondering if there was a better way to do it (not that that's a bad way).  I've decided to use the `get_static_prefix` template tag from `static` instead.  Somehow feels more django-esque.