# Django - Custom inclusion template tag MEDIA_URL?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following custom inclusion tag:

```
from django.template import Library
from django.db.models import Count

register = Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('projects/work_part.html', takes_context=True)
def project_list(context):
    return {'projects':context['projects']}
```

My settings look like this:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'context_processors.default_processors',
    )
```

I need to access MEDIA_URL within the work_path.html template but it seems the context processors are not applied to custom templates.

How do I access MEDIA_URL within my template tag? I saw this post: [Access STATIC_URL from within a custom inclusion template tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457737/access-static-url-from-within-a-custom-inclusion-template-tag) but I am not using STATIC_URL, is there another set of tags I should be loading?

Comment: As mentioned in the first answer to the thread you linked: Why don't you import MEDIA_URL in your template tag code and pass it to the template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the same (as with `STATIC_URL`) using the tempatetag [*`{% get_media_prefix %}`*](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/templatetags/static.py#L69)

Comment: Oh man do I feel stupid, I don't know why I didn't think to try that. Thanks!

Comment: When you get a `TemplateSyntaxError` because the tag doesn't exist, see user1653114's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12307683/400691

Answer (score 15):

The get_media_prefix tag is in static for those of us that were looking to "load media"...

```
{% load static %}
...
<img class="img" src="{% get_media_prefix %}{{ obj.image }}" alt="{{ obj.name }}" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Or you can just ignore those template tag and use `MEDIA_URL` variable right away. All of the variables from `settings.py` are accessible from the template HTML.

```
<img class="img" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ obj.image }}" alt="{{ obj.name }}" />
```

Comment: that's exactly _NOT_ working for the questioner, hence the question in the first place.