# including css in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm new to Django, and i'm having hard time including css styles in a template.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457737/access-static-url-from-within-a-custom-inclusion-template-tag) and tried to do the same but it's not working for me.

my Template:

```
{% load static %}<html><head><link href="{% get_static_prefix %}/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /></head><body>
```

the HTML i get:

```
<head><link href="C:/Users/Nayish/workspace/am/src/am/static/style.css"rel='stylesheet'type='text/css' /></head>
```

Note that this is the folder containing my css.

Thanks, Boris.

Comment: Are you trying to serve them statically or just reference the css file?

Comment: either one is fine...but the 2'ed would be better.

Comment: Could you please update your question with the version of Django that you're using? Handling static files changed a little in Django 1.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you aren't using static css sheets.  I always just do:

```
<html>
<head>
            {%block stylesheet %}
               <style type="text/css" title="currentStyle"> 
                   @import "{{MEDIA_URL}}css/style.css";
               </style>
            {% endblock stylesheet%}
   ....
```

I then set my Media root, and store the files as

```
 MEDIA_ROOT=<fullyquallified patyh>/Media/css/<css files>
 MEDIA_URL=http://localhost/mysite/
```

It should be noted that `STATIC_URL` defaults to `MEDIA_URL` if its not defined.

Comment: isn't Media root suppose to store user uploaded files? is that a good practice?

Comment: No, site_media (or whatever you set it to) is for all your projects static resources. That includes uploads, but it's also your images, javascript, CSS, etc.

Comment: @chrisdpratt: that's not quite true anymore with Django 1.3's ``staticfiles`` app (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/). It's not wrong, either, you are not forced to use ``staticfiles``.

Comment: Ok, I should have phrased it better. I meant to convey simply that media root is not just for uploads as Boris though. It doesn't *have* to be for anything else (you're not required to store other static media files there), but it's not exclusive to uploads.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you haven't mixed up the [`STATIC_ROOT`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-root) and [`STATIC_URL`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-url) settings.

`STATIC_ROOT` defines where the files are on the storage system (usually your local hard disc for local development), while `STATIC_URL` defines the URL from where the server serves them. The second one is usually referred to in templates, and it is also the value that the `{% get_static_prefix %}` template tag returns.