# can't locate the css file for a website

Tags: html, css, django, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [including css in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125661/including-css-in-django)

I have not much experience with web-front.

I'm trying to integrate a forum app into django. ( http://www.pybbm.org )

I succeeded running the app(I can see the forum at `http://localhost/forum/` )
But it looks horrible without any css.

I tried including all the `css files` and `less files` I find in www.pybbm.org but it doesn't seem to help to make it look better.

Can anyone take a look at where the css files are for the site?

Comment: Where did you try including them?

Comment: I added to my base.html header. with full url to the site's css

Comment: I can see the css applied on my system.

Answer (score 0):

the abreviation of CSS is Cascading StyleSheet, so it is responsible for the lay-out of the website. A css file is likely stored in a directory called CSS or style or sometimes in the main directory.
What you could do to find the css file is opening the index.html file and search for a file with extension .css.  You can find the line of text at the head of the index.html file.
When you found the .css file, you also see where it is saved, like /main/style/style.css
Problem solved?