# Django 1.3 Static Files

Tags: python, django

Like the 1 billionth static file question about Django 1.3. I've been searching and trying so many things but nothing seems to work for me. Any help would be appreciated. Will try and give as much information as possible.

URL FILE

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^projectm/statictest/$','project_management.views.statictest'),)
```

VIEW

```
def statictest(request):
return render_to_response('statictest.html',locals())
```

TEMPLATE

```
<html><head><title>Static Load Test Page</title></head>
<body>
{% load static %}
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}testimage.jpg" />
</body></html>
```

SETTINGS

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/baz/framework/mysite/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ('',)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
"/home/baz/framework/mysite/templates"
```

FILES

```
-bash-3.2$ pwd
/home/baz/framework/mysite/templates
statictest.html

-bash-3.2$ pwd
/home/baz/framework/mysite/project_management/static
-bash-3.2$ ls
testimage.jpg
```

Not too sure if there is any other information that would be helpful. But basically when I go to this test page and check the page source, the url is pointing to

```
<img src="/static/testimage.jpg" />
```

However the image does not load. I have tried this on multiple browsers too. Maybe I am missing an imort statement somewhere?

cheers for the help

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the built in `runserver` command or do you serve the Django app some other way?

If you use `runserver` then your problem is that you don't tell Django where to find your static assets in the filesystem. You need to set STATIC_ROOT to a filesystem path where your static assets can be found. Try setting it to: `/home/baz/framework/mysite/project_management/static/`

If you are using a different server (like gunicorn behind Nginx for example) then it is the responsibility of the front-end server to intercept requests for `/static/` and serve them for you.

Comment: STATIC_ROOT is where runserver looks for files to serve (only works when DEBUG=True). It is also where Django copies static files during collectstatic. The collectstatic command, by default, looks for static files in /static/ in each app plus in any dirs listed in STATICFILES_DIRS.

Comment: Yes I am using the built it runserver.

Answer (score 0):

Also remember to run the ‘collectstatic’ management command once you have set ‘STATIC_ROOT’.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/#deploying-static-files-in-a-nutshell

Comment: Hi, okay so I updated the STATIC_ROOT setting in my config file. Performed a python manage.py collectstatic. I can see it has collected the testimage from my apps static folder, but when I refresh the page the image still doesn't load, and the path is simply imgsrc='testimage.jpg' .

Comment: Since you're testing this with the built-in runserver you'll need to tweak your urls.py a little bit, [see here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development). Now once that's done and your server is running, try to access the image directly by going to `http://your-url/static/testimage.jpg` – if that works ok but the template is still outputting "src='testimage.jpg'" instead of "src='/static/testimage.jpg'" then you're not using RequestContext when the template is rendered, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11684482/1428653).

Comment: I was thinking it could have been something to do with permissions so I tried chmodding the the static directories to 777 but to no avail.

Comment: try `{% get_static_prefix %}`. ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457737/access-static-url-from-within-a-custom-inclusion-template-tag/5457817#5457817

Comment: Hey Matt,I changed the imgsrc to "/static/testimage.jpg" and it seemed to work. It pulled it out of the project app folder. But when I use the static tag it breaks again. I'm sure I am doing something wrong in the settings or something. thanks

Comment: I changed it to the get_static_prefix tag instead of the STATIC tag and it worked! I might have changed some things along the way to make it work that way, not too sure. Appreciate the help guys, truly. :)